# Font Family Open Sans not being used

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I am using [Google's Open Sans Font](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans) in my application.

I have defined the stylesheet as instructed:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700'
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I then used it on the body selector as:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I have not defined font family anywhere else. I assume that since I have defined it at the parent, the child elements will automatically inherit it.

However, if I open up the inspector for say an anchor tag in my application and see the computed styles for that tag, I find that (Chrome Latest) the "Rendered Font" says "Times New Roman 18 glyphs" - Is this correct? I was expecting it to say "Open Sans" - Is the Open Sans font not being applied?

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Does the text *look* like Open Sans? It should be clearly distinguishable from Times New Roman. “Rendered Font” info in Chrome can be bogus for web fonts.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Please see the answer - apparently its some kind of bug with chrome (because I don't have the issue with Firefox)

Answer (score 11):

Check out the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/PGxVmg). Its working fine for me !

```css
.open-sans-font{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="open-sans-font">
   Stackoverflow rocks !!!
</div>
```