# Font family Open Sans not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I'm using [Open Sans font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) for my website but it is not working across all computer and I can't figure it why.

I'm calling it in my `<head>` tag. I tried `https` or `http` or `//` and the result is the same.

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

It is well loaded from the browser (status 200).

My CSS looks like this:

```
body{
  font-family: OpenSans;
}
```

But my text are rendered with some sans-serif font besides the fact that it mention Open Sans in the CSS inspector. Even if I remove all font-family from the CSS inspector in my Chrome browser, the font doesn't change. Also, if I add !important, nothing change.

What can be the source of this issue?

*I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908040/font-family-open-sans-not-being-used) without success.*

I don't think it's a conflict because it's working on some computer.

Comment: you'll have to show us your CSS as well

Comment: You probably have a conflicting style with a higher specificity. See [this calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for more information on how to calculate selector specificity. Add `body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; }` to your stylesheet. If the `!important;` added to the end works, it supports this theory that a style is overriding your original `Open Sans` font-family declaration. Look through your browser developer tools, find the style and remove it. Make sure to remove `!important;` as well. It will help to debug but ***should not*** continue to be used..

Comment: also, check that your URL works. I forget but there's certain situations where the `//` won't work (might be certain browsers)

Comment: injecting `<link href="..." type='text/css' />` alone isn't enough to use font on site. You also should add `<style>body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important; }</style>` right after the link tag, as @War10ck suggested.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, my main error was to use `font-family: OpenSans;` instead of `font-family: 'Open Sans';`

Answer (score 7):

did you try to reference your CSS with https?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I tried this with JSFiddle and it work in my Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/doqvqfhe/1/

Could you give some more code?

Answer (score 3):

I use font-family "Open Sans", It works instead of "OpenSans".